# Как получить текст, который находится после тегов <br>?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как можно получить текст, который находится между тегами, (библиотеку любую могу использовать, но лучше JSOUP) например:

```html
<div class="123">
    <div class="spoiler-title "><b>....</b></div>
    <br>Текст который нужно взять`введите сюда код`
    <div class="spoiler-body">....</div>
</div>
<br>Текст который нужно взять`введите сюда код
<hr>
<div class="spoiler-title "><b>....</b></div>
```

Как можно получить текст между дивами? Я попробовал братьев взять, но текста там не было(

Как можно по другому?

Answer (score 0):

First way:
1) Use Scanner to read line by line. [Link, if you forgot how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311266/read-line-with-scanner?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
2) Use "split" to split line by `<br>` and assign that to `String[] array`
3) after add `line = array[1];`

Second way:
1) Find index (position) of the tag and use `substring` to cut string. [Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615749/java-method-to-get-position-of-a-match-in-a-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Nadeyus eto pomozhet

**Translation:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Please, translate answer to russian, I think, that every online translater can do it with acceptable quality

Comment: @ЮрийСПб translated

Comment: @Antonio112009 перевод стоило бы запостить как текст.